# polymorphic associations and case sensitivity in rails 3 with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a simple polymorphic association (tags) in Rails 3 where the taggable_type is set to a model name such as user, event, group etc. the names in the db field are lowercase, the query that is looking for taggable_type(model name) is looking for a model name with an uppercase first letter like User, Event or Group. This is preventing my polymorphic associations from being found. Is there a way I can fix this behavior? It was working with MySQL but I am in the process of moving the project to Postgres for various other important reasons so I need to sort this out.

Comment: How was your association setup in the first place?  The `taggable_type` should have always been "uppercase first letter like User, Event or Group...".

Comment: It's actually strange. Looking at the currently deployed project, when taggable_type is a Post it's uppercased but "User" is being stored all lowercase in the taggable_type field. I'll have to dig around and see what is causing this. I probably didn't notice it before because MySQL was doing a case-insensitive search.

Comment: Ah, found the issue. It was being manually set incorrectly in a few places. Thanks for the help.